# How can I insert element to vector instead the element already exists in the vector?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

How can I insert `7` to `v1[0]` instead the value that already exists at `v1[0]`, given the following code:

```
std::vector<int> v1;
v1.push_back(1);
v1.push_back(3);
std::cout << "The size of v1:  " << v1.size() << std::endl; // output: 2
v1.insert(v1.begin(), 7);
std::cout << "The size of v1:  " << v1.size() << std::endl; // output: 3 (I want that it's will be "2")
std::cout << v1[0] << " ," << v1[1] << " ," << v1[2]; // 7 ,1 ,3
```

But , I want that `v1` will contain only two elements : `7 , 3` !

Comment: maybe   `v1[0] = 7;`  ?

Comment: If you are careful with the language, the standard API names might make more sense. "[Insert](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/insert)" means "put into"; if you put a jellybean into a jar that already has 2 jellybeans, you end up with a jar that has 3 jellybeans, similar to your vector. So "insert" is not the word you want to use in your question.

Answer (score 1):

When you do `v1.insert(v1.begin(), 7)`, you are just inserting an element at the beginning of v1. You don't expect that, after inserting an element, the number of elements stays the same.

I think what you want is simply `v1[0] = 7`.

Answer (score 0):

You might misunderstand what `insert()` does.
If you do `v1.insert(position, value);`, you are inserting the `value` at the `position` and any elements after `position` inside`v1` would be shifted one position to the right.

```
v1: 1,3
   ^
insert 7
```

This is something you did in your code.
You might need `v1[0] = 7;//v1[position] = value`. This changes the element at the `position 0` to `7`.